# Bringing a European pendant lamp back to the US, and changing it from hardwire to plugin

Tags: lighting, lamp

I'm in Spain and want to purchase this beautiful pendant lamp. I've done some research and it seems I'll be able to use a US bulb pretty easily. However, the lamp is hardwired and my apartment doesn't have a place to install it. Can I use a basic US hardwire to plug in conversion kit or would I need to rewire the whole lamp? I know the European wires are lighter than ours because of the voltage difference. And how much would that cost/where do I find someone to do it? I'm also open to DIY! Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about a few pictures of the lamp.

Comment: What does "hardwired" mean? Do you mean it plugs into the wall? Replacing plugs is easy to do. For $3 in materials and some tools (wire stripper, solder and iron with flux) you can change a Euro conformant 2 or 3 wire plug to US. Does it label the voltage?

Answer (score 2):

Pictures will help us to answer more specifically. Given what you have said so far, I can tell you the following:

1. Incandescent style lamps in the US are pretty standard, with lots of interchangeable parts available. If you can't come up with a solution yourself, a lighting store can rewire the whole fixture to use standard US-style hardware unless it uses incredibly specialized parts. It almost certainly does not use parts that are too specialized for conversion.
2. If it has a standard E26 or E27 Edison socket and a reasonable quality cord already, you can install a plug and start using it. Replacement plugs are commonly available at hardware stores, easy to install, and totally legal for use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the lamp is hanging from the ceiling and hard wired there. You can use a swag chain arrangement and run the power from the lamp to a wall, then down to an outlet. You can also run wire molding from an outlet up the wall and over to the lamp. Both are allowed and the material needed is readily available at home stores.